# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'my returned value' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get this error in this simple SQL statement when trying to retrieve a string from a table.

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prViewRequirements, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cardiac Assessment Questionnaire by Dr.' to data type int.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[prViewRequirements]   Script Date: 04/24/2013 15:44:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prViewRequirements]
    @WFRouteID int

AS

DECLARE 
@DocumentDescription VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @DocumentDescription = DocumentDescription
            FROM tbFollowOnTracking
            WHERE WFRouteID = @WFRouteID
            AND IsActive = 1


            IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
                GOTO ERRSP      

        RETURN @DocumentDescription

ERRSP:
    RETURN -1
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Which line is line 18?

Comment: Line 18 is - WHERE WFRouteID = @WFRouteID

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to return a varchar instead of int.

```
RETURN @DocumentDescription
```

Please either do

```
select @DocumentDescription
```

or use an output parameter (Recommended)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prViewRequirements]
    @WFRouteID int
    , @DocumentDescription varchar(100) = null output
```

UPDATE - Here is the whole procedure:

```
alter procedure dbo.prViewRequirements
    @WFRouteID int
    , @DocumentDescription varchar(100) = null output
AS

select @DocumentDescription = '' -- Init

select @DocumentDescription = DocumentDescription
from tbFollowOnTracking
where WFRouteID = @WFRouteID
and IsActive = 1

return 0
go

/* Examples
declare @DocumentDescription varchar(100) = ''

exec dbo.prViewRequirements @WFRouteID = 10, @DocumentDescription  = @DocumentDescription output

select @DocumentDescription 
*/
```

Comment: I keep getting NULL returned for each result.

Comment: It worked for me. Please copy and paste the keyword OUTPUT carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prViewRequirements]

      @WFRouteID INT
    , @DocumentDescription VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT

AS BEGIN

    SELECT @DocumentDescription = t.DocumentDescription
    FROM dbo.tbFollowOnTracking t
    WHERE t.WFRouteID = @WFRouteID
        AND t.IsActive = 1

    IF @DocumentDescription IS NULL
        RETURN -1    

    RETURN 0

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
alter procedure dbo.prViewRequirements
    @WFRouteID int
    , @DocumentDescription varchar(100) = null output
AS

BEGIN
select @DocumentDescription = '' -- Init

select @DocumentDescription = DocumentDescription
from tbFollowOnTracking
where WFRouteID = @WFRouteID
and IsActive = 1

END
```

Execute the proc as shown below

```
DECLARE @res varchar(100)
exec dbo.prViewRequirements @WFRouteID,@DocumentDescription=@res OUTPUT
select @res
```